# Excel doesn't automatically update ranges in SUMIF expression -- why?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2007, worksheet-function, autocomplete

In Excel 2007, I have a worksheet arranged like this:

```
            A           B           C
1           x           2           15
2           x           3           45
3           x           4           46
4           x           1           7
5           x           2           85
6           x           1           14
7           x           1           9
8           x           3           36
9           x           1           5
10              
11          C Total:                262
12          C Total where B > 1:    227
```

`C11` is a regular `SUM`:

```
=SUM(C$1:C9)
```

`C12` is a `SUMIF` that only counts the value in column `C` if the value in `B` is greater than 1:

```
=SUMIF(B$1:B9, ">1", C$1:C9)
```

Here's my problem: I insert a row at row `10`, and add additional data:

```
9           x           1           5
10          y           1           17
11
12          C Total:                265
13          C Total where B > 1:    227
```

After entering the data at `C10`, Excel helpfully automatically updates the range in the `SUM` formula, but **not** the `SUMIF`:

```
=SUM(C$1:C10)

=SUMIF(B$1:B9, ">1", C$1:C9)
```

I commonly update this worksheet one row at a time, so I lose a fair amount of time having to adjust the ranges in the formula.

Is there a reason Excel doesn't automatically update the ranges in `SUMIF`, like it does with `SUM`? Can it be made to do so, or is there a workaround for the behaviour?

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing my SUM formulas extend automatically like you're describing... Workaround: extend your SUMIF formula to include a blank row and insert above that blank row going forward. Alternatively, use find/replace to fix the ranges in your SUMIF more easily.

Comment: @variant Actually, it does as soon as you enter values in the newly inserted rows (tested on Excel:mac 2011).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have observed in the case of `SUM` is Excel’s [automatic formula expansion](http://www.bettersolutions.com/excel/EED883/YI824010881.htm) in action – the bit of magic Excel performs to adjust formula references when you add rows or columns. As `SUM` and `SUMIF` are very similar (they share the ability to restrict themselves to the part of a range filled with data, for instance – see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726673.aspx#xlAllowExtraData)), one would rightly expect both to be targeted by formula expansion. The fact `SUMIF` is not, or at least not on Office 2007 and Office:mac 2011, I would call buggy behavior (it might not technically be a bug). I’m afraid there is nothing you can do to change this.

Comment: Outlining how to work around this is beyond the scope of your question – check [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/337435/how-exactly-do-i-create-dynamic-named-ranges) for some pointers.

Comment: Thanks. This is the closest anyone has come to being able to answer this, including myself. =)

Answer (score 1):

You have have to make the data into a Table.

ExcelIsFun has a video about it on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVUxJQtf4HY&list=PL3FBEE51974F03CCF&index=18&feature=plpp_video).