# How exactly do I create "Dynamic Named Ranges"?

Tags: microsoft-excel, java, named-ranges

I'm trying to create a "Dynamic Named Range" in Excel so I can populate an X/Y values table inside of it in Java.
I've seen tutorials, but I still don't get it. I know I have to use the `=OFFSET()` function, but where? Within the chart? Somewhere else?

I'm sorry, it's because my Excel level sucks... I haven't used it for a looong time.

Comment: I've tried a lot of things!!! :( Because this function has to be inside of a chart (after further investigation)... so i've tried: =OFFSET(Sheet1!$I$29,0,0,COUNT($I$29:$I$999),1)

=OFFSET(Sheet1!$I$29,0,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$I$29:Sheet1!$I$9999),1)

And nothing seems to work, Excel doesn't like it. Can anyone help me please??? :(

Comment: Put that formula in a cell, and click the fx button to get the formula wizard. That may help you to track what's wrong.

Comment: Try replacing `Sheet1!$I$29:Sheet1!$I$9999` by `Sheet1!$I$29:$I$9999` to simplify

Comment: Yea, tried that, but it didn't work either :(

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to create a named range (Insert, Name, Define in xl2003). Enter myRange (or any other name) as the name to define, and the formula in the "refers to" box.
To help you build the formula, you cand read [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm), [this](http://www.exceluser.com/explore/dynname1.htm) and [this](http://www.contextures.com/xlnames01.html).
You can test if your named range works by using entering in a cell `=count(myRange)` or a similar formula.

Finally, you build your chart using the range name as usual, but you replace the `=Sheet1!$C$4:$C$10` in the data range by `=myRange`.

Comment: One more thing, whenever i try to write on an excel cell in java, i get a NullPointerException when i get the cell, and since its empty, it gets a null, and when i do: x.setCellValue being x = null -> exception!!! :) is there any way to avoid this? is there any null value in Excel?